# Which distribution is this code stand for?

Tags: c++, statistics, distribution, normal-distribution

I am reading a pice of code that generate random numbers. But I don't know which distribution it is. Could anyone tell me which distribution it is?

```
#include<cmath>
double rand(double min, double max)
{
    return min+(max-min)*rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0);
}
double normal(double x, double miu,double sigma)
{
    return 1.0/sqrt(2*pi)/sigma*exp(-1*(x-miu)*(x-miu)/(2*sigma*sigma));
}
double randn(double miu,double sigma, double min ,double max)
{
    double x,y,dScope;
    do{
        x=rand(min,max);
        y=normal(x,miu,sigma);
        dScope=rand(0.0,normal(miu,miu,sigma));
    }while(dScope>y);
    return x;
}
```

I invoked the function randn with parameter(0,0.01,-0.6,0.6). I want to know Which distribution does randn stand for? It confused me a lot, what does dScope used for?
There are 14951 sample in total. The histogram are as bellow:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to draw a histogram?

Comment: @Alex wait a minute, I'll try that.

Comment: Which function parameters did you use?

Comment: @Alex I added in the question, please have a look at.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a normal distribution (it goes from -Infinity to +Infinity), but truncated normal distribution, sampled via acceptance/rejection method in the interval [min...max]. Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

Answer (score 0):

`randn` generates number using Normal or Gaussian distribution. The bell-shaped probability density function (your histogram is similar to it) is the key identifier of this distribution.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution Wikipedia article about this distribution.

Comment: No, it is not a normal distribution